# Merge CSV Files based on ID even when Unmatched IDS and Indefinite Number of Columns

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, csv, join

I'm writing a bash script and part of the process requires to piece csv files together whilst preserving the integrity of the columns; for example I have two files in the following format:

F1

```
ID,MD,L1,L2,L3,GD,L4
12,OB,AA,PP,AA,TT,AA
15,OB,PP,PP,PP,TT,AA
```

F2

```
ID,MD,L7,L8,L9,L10,GD
13,OB,PP,AA,AA,AA,AA
15,OB,PP,PP,PP,AA,AA
```

The output would look as detailed below, in which the unmatched ID returns the value NM and the repeated column -in this case "GD"- is displayed according to the value per file:

```
ID,MD,L1,L2,L3,GD,L4,L7,L8,L9,L10,GD
12,OB,AA,PP,AA,TT,AA,NM,NM,NM,NM,NM
13,NM,NM,NM,NM,NM,NM,PP,AA,AA,AA,AA
15,OB,PP,PP,PP,TT,AA,PP,PP,PP,AA,AA
```

I've been trying to make `join` work as it seemed promising i.e. 
`join -t, -eNM -a1 -a2 -o 0,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8,2.3,... F1 F2`

but I'm running through some problems.

1. If I use the `-o` option it presumes I know the exact number of columns per file, which instead vary independently.
2. Errors leaked into result:
   `join: REPORT_2|15-10-2019|15:39:25.csv:5: is not sorted: 04181646`

if there are other alternatives instead of `join` I am open to suggestions. thnks.

Comment: Get rid of the `...`s that are cluttering your sample input and output and making it harder to tell what you want and test with it.

Comment: I do not understand the way you choose GD value. In the fist file for ID 15, GD value is TT. In the second file for ID 15, GD value is AA. Why in the output file, for ID 15, GD is AA and not TT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a shell script to create the necessary `-o` options for you and to sort the data of your input files.

This assumes that the second field `MD` is present in both input files and only printed once in the output (skipped in the options for the second file).

```
#!/bin/bash

opts="0,"

# file1: get number of columms - 1 from the first line
numcols=$(awk -F',' '(NR==1) {print NF-1}' "$1")

# file1: add options
for i in $(seq "$numcols"); do
  opts+=$(printf '1.%s,' "$((i+1))")
done

# file2: get number of columms - 2 from the first line
numcols=$(awk -F',' '(NR==1) {print NF-2}' "$2")

# file2: add options
for i in $(seq "$numcols"); do
  opts+=$(printf '2.%s,' "$((i+2))")
done

opts=${opts:0:-1} # remove the last `,`

join -t, --header -eNM -a1 -a2 -o "$opts"\
  <(head -n1 "$1"; tail -n+2 "$1" | sort -nk1,1)\
  <(head -n1 "$2"; tail -n+2 "$2" | sort -nk1,1)
```

I added option `--header` to treat the first line as header line. The `<(head -n1 "$1"; tail -n+2 "$1" | sort -nk1,1)` is used to print the header line and sort the remaining lines by the first field numerically.

Make the script executable

```
chmod +x join.sh
```

and run it as

```
./join.sh file1 file2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), you can run

```
mlr --csv join  -u --ul --ur -j ID -f input_01.csv  \
then unsparsify \
then put -S 'for (k in $*) { if ($[k] =~ "^$") { $[k]="NM" }}' \
input_02.csv
```

and obtain

```
ID,MD,L7,L8,L9,L10,L1,L2,L3,L4
13,OB,PP,AA,AA,AA,NM,NM,NM,NM
15,OB,PP,PP,PP,AA,PP,PP,PP,AA
12,OB,NM,NM,NM,NM,AA,PP,AA,AA
```

Comment: This solution is excellent but I came across an unexpected scenario. Both files, eventually have a column-header in common and 'mlr' picks only one of them. If there is an option to either display both or evaluate them in a boolean fashion I would appreciate to be pointed in the right direction. As a side note, one can replace the `put` option with `unsparsify --fill-with NM`

Comment: Please @AF.BJ could you edit in your question your input and output example files? In this way for me it could be simpler. Thank you